# Buffer exceeded limit WCF despite adding maRecievedMessageSize attribute to binding element

Tags: c#, wcf

I keep getting this error when debugging my WCF service in VS17

[Buffer Exceeded limit error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwwBi.png)

However, I have gone through all of this before and it was working up until I re-installed VS. I double checked to make sure I was connected to my database in the ServerWindow and I definitely have the buffer set to more than 65536.

[EDIT] Also I have checked the client projects I have built that are referencing and consuming this service, just in case, they are all set to the same endpoint as is detailed in this app.config and their buffer sizes are set the same as this service as well.

Here is my app.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
        <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" />
        <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
          <providers>
            <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" 

      type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers. 
   ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipPro vider, System.Web.Extensions, 
    Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
    serviceUri="" />
          </providers>
        </membership>
        <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
          <providers>
            <add name="ClientRoleProvider" 
    type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, 
    System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
          </providers>
        </roleManager>
      </system.web>
      <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config 
    file must be added to the host's 
      app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for 
    libraries. -->
      <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
          <service name="MBM.Services.MBMExtClientService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
    contract="MBM.Services.IMBMExtClientService">
              <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
              </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
    contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add 
     baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_T 
    ime_Addresses/MBMServices/MBMExtClientService/" />
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
          </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
              set the values below to false before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging 
    purposes, 
              set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
              to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="LargeBuffer" maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
    maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
      </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: What makes you think that LargeBuffer is being used by anything?

Comment: It might have been useful to state in your question that you were using the WCF Test Client.

Comment: @Tim literally the first line of the post dude: "I keep getting this error when debugging my WCF service in VS17"

Comment: The correct way to mark a question as complete is to *accept* an answer. If you've solved this yourself, feel free to write it up *as* an answer, post it and accept it (after the enforced time delay). Make sure it does stand up well as an answer. We *don't* edit titles here to indicate the question state.

Comment: @Medicineman25 - Actually, you can debug WCF services directly in VS *without*  using WCF Test Client.  I've done it more times than I can count.  Hence my comment above.